# Issue creating Docker image - error /node_modules/dotenv-checker: Command failed

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, package.json

I am getting the following error when building a docker image for nodejs project

```
\#11 160.7 \[5/5\] Building fresh packages...
\#11 162.5 error /node_modules/dotenv-checker: Command failed.
\#11 162.5 Exit code: 1
\#11 162.5 Command: node ./src/scripts/add-script-to-package.js
\#11 162.5 Arguments:
\#11 162.5 Directory: /node_modules/dotenv-checker
\#11 162.5 Output:
\#11 162.5 internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
\#11 162.5   throw err;
\#11 162.5   ^
\#11 162.5
\#11 162.5 Error: Cannot find module 'package.json'
\#11 162.5 Require stack:
\#11 162.5 - /node_modules/dotenv-checker/src/scripts/add-script-to-package.js
\#11 162.5     at Function.Module.\_resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
\#11 162.5     at Function.Module.\_load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
\#11 162.5     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
\#11 162.5     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
\#11 162.5     at Object.\<anonymous\> (/node_modules/dotenv-checker/src/scripts/add-script-to-package.js:23:21)
\#11 162.5     at Module.\_compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
\#11 162.5     at Object.Module.\_extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
\#11 162.5     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
\#11 162.5     at Function.Module.\_load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
\#11 162.5     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint \[as runMain\] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12) {
\#11 162.5   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
\#11 162.5   requireStack: \[
\#11 162.5     '/node_modules/dotenv-checker/src/scripts/add-script-to-package.js'
\#11 162.5   \]
\#11 162.5 }
```

dockerfile

```
FROM node:14 as builder

COPY ./package.json ./yarn.lock ./turbo.json ./

RUN yarn install
```

It is throwing the above error at yarn install

Does it have anything to do with node version? my project has dependency on node 14 so can't use 16.

Please let me know if I am missing anything or if I need to try anything specific.

Thank you